# Understanding when and how to use Require.JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've just begun to work with Require.JS and I'm a bit unclear on the appropriate cases in which it should be used, as well as the correct way to use it in those cases.

Here's how I currently have things set up with Require.JS. I have two functions, `functionA()` and `functionB()`. Both of these functions require an additional function, `functionC()` to work properly.

I only want to load functionC() when necessary, i.e. when functionA() or functionB() is going to be called. So I have the following files:

**functionC.js**

```
functionC(){
  //do stuff
}
```

**functionA.js**

```
functionA(){  
  define(['functionC'],function(){
    //functionC() is loaded because it is listed as a dependency, so we can proceed
    //do some functionA() stuff
  });
}
```

**functionB.js**

```
functionB(){  
  define(['functionC'],function(){
    //functionC() is loaded because it is listed as a dependency, so we can proceed
    //do some functionB() stuff
  });
}
```

So, is this set up correctly? And if I end up calling both functionA() and functionB() on the same page, is extra work being done since they both load the functionC.js file? If so, is that a problem? And if so, is there a way to set it up so that they first check to see if functionC.js has been loaded yet, and only load it if it hasn't been? Finally, is this an appropriate use of Require.JS?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`define()` should only be used to define a module. For the above example, where a piece of code should be dynamically loaded, using `require()` is more appropriate:

**functionA.js**

```
functionA(){
  require(['functionC'],function(functionC){
    //use funcC in here to call functionC
  });
}
```

Some notes:

- `require([])` is asynchronous, so if the caller of `functionA` is expecting a return value from that function, there will likely be errors. It is best if `functionA` accepts a callback that is called when `functionA` is done with its work.
- The above code will call `require()` for every call to `functionA`; however, after the first call, there is no penalty taken to load `functionC.js`, it is only loaded once. The first time `require()` gets called, it will load `functionC.js`, but the rest of the time, RequireJS knows it is already loaded, so it will call the `function(functionC){}` function without requesting `functionC.js` again.

Comment: Thanks for your response--it helps a lot. define() vs. require() was something I needed clarification on, and your other two bullet points really help a lot. I think the first of the bullet points is something I still need to understand better--how to correctly handle the asynchronous nature of RequireJS.

Answer (score 22):

You can find details about RequireJS and JavaScript modularity here: [JavaScript modularity with RequireJS (from spaghetti code to ravioli code)](http://netmvc.blogspot.be/2012/11/javascript-modularity-with-requirejs.html)

Comment: top link - having read numerous tutorials, that is by far the best. clear and concise. +1

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.