# Resolving circular dependencies for requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, circular-dependency

We have a ton of typescript files that use external modules and we're hitting circular dependencies. (I've looked at other questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264827/circular-dependencies-in-modules-using-requirejs) but none appear to answer my specific question.) This is in typescript so we're constrained to the way it generates the javascript.

1. First off, is there a tool that will read through all my files (the .ts or the .js) and flag the places where I have circular dependencies? I think we can eliminate most if we can identify them.
2. We have several cases where the design we must model forces circular dependencies. Is there a way to handle this in requireJS (again as created by typescript)?
3. Is the answer to have the typescript compiler create a single .js file from all the .ts files? And if so, is there any downside to this approach, both when debugging and in production?

thanks - dave

Comment: For 3.: If you use `--out FILE` as a compiler flag, all files will be concatenated into the specified file.

Comment: Suggest you to try a webpack with ts-loader for production builds. And you can look here for an intresting plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a tool that will read through all my files (the .ts or the .js) and flag the places where I have circular dependencies?

Atom-TypeScript can do circular dependency analysis : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/dependency-view.md#circular

Also this looks interesting : https://www.npmjs.org/package/madge

> Is there a way to handle this in requireJS

You get undefined initially but then you can `require` again : http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

> Is the answer to have the typescript compiler create a single .js file from all the .ts files? And if so, is there any downside to this approach, both when debugging and in production?

Yes `--out`. -ves : slower compile times, *must* use sourcemaps for debugging. *inability* to lazy load parts of the codebase at production times.

Comment: On the circular issue with require link - the .js created by typescript follows the suggestions, but requireJS is still hitting an error trying to load on a circular reference. Is something else required for the typescript generated .js?

Comment: And Madge looks perfect, but it requires sudo and I'm on Windows :(

Comment: On the circular issue with require link - the .js created by typescript follows the suggestions, but requireJS is still hitting an error trying to load on a circular reference. Is something else required for the typescript generated - no. Can you share the TS?

Comment: I am trying to pull out a simple example. The problem is as soon as I simplify it, the problem goes away. On the plus side, one of those simplifications works for us, so we're good now. But still, I want to find out what is going on here.

Comment: @DavidThielen I wrote this just for you, Atom TypeScript now does circular dependency analysis : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/dependency-view.md#circular